# Delphi register a dbexpress dll (dbexpsda40.dll) & Windows Service is failing to start and uninstall

Tags: sql-server, delphi, dll, delphi-xe6, dbexpress

We have a windows service using this DbExpress Driver for SQL Server 8.2.1.0, Previously this service used to start and work normally now it is not starting and not uninstalling also. We use this Driver on a Server system to connect to our database, Now it is not establishing a connection and failing.
When I try to start the service from services.msc screen is throwing the below error

> A timeout was reached (30000 milliseconds) while waiting for the TIPQA
> Server service to connect. The TIPQA Server service failed to start
> due to the following error
>
> The service did not respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion.

When I checked the registry I observed that the dll location is pointing to the different version which is mentioned in the registry.
[image: Registry screen shot]

So I tried to unregister the dll and register it again with the same exact version (8.2.1.0).
I have tried using the cmd in admin mode using the regsvr32.exe but I got some errors like below
[image: Regsvr32.exe error]

To fix this issue I have added some code and ran the same regsvr32 cmd in the command prompt with admin privileges
[image: Code]

this command is successful with this message but I can't see any changes in the registry after restart also.
[image: Successful]

Can someone please tell me if there is any other way to register this dll update the registry?

Comment: Why do you not provide the requested information to your [devart question](https://forums.devart.com/viewtopic.php?f=10&t=44544&sid=48854bbbaab39d54d0a6aabeac563a77). Seems you have a bigger issue with your application if you have no useful logging / error information logging - should probably address that first.

Comment: What do Devart say about this?  It's their Dll ...

Comment: I tried by deleting all unwated instances of the dll and started everything from scrath. It worked